# Opening IntelliJ's settings dialog freezes the all IDE for few minutes

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time I open IntelliJ's Settings dialog I need to wait few minutes until I can do anything. also every thing I try to do with-in the setting dialog after it been Released makes it freeze again! for few minutes.
I am using IntelliJ 14.1.4 (64bit) and the vmoptions are:

```
-server
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024M
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:-TraceClassUnloading
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

couldn't find anything related to this issue on the web.
thanks for the helpers

Comment: how much RAM do you actually have?

Comment: @leeor I got 16GB RAM

Comment: I recommend following Jetbrains' [guide for reporting performance problems](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827577-Reporting-performance-problems) and reporting it to them.

Comment: Agree with Bohuslav, also Automatic thread dumps in the log directory should be enough to know what is going on: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827507-Getting-a-thread-dump-when-IDE-hangs-and-doesn-t-respond